# Access JSON value from Alamofire response

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am making a request to a local server that returns the following JSON:

`{"session_key":"somecodexyz1234"}`

The following code is is used to attempt to print the `session_key value. But this is always evaluated to`nil`.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
response in
print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")

print("Response code: \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")


if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
}}

if response.data  != nil {
    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

    // changes 
    if let arr : NSArray = json as? NSArray
    {
          let sk = arr.value(forKey: "session_key") as? String
          if sk != nil {print(sk)}
    }
}
```

The following is output (the `print(sk)` is not executed as it is nil):

```
Request: Optional(http://127.0.0.1:5000/code)
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800023f260> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/code } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 40;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 23 Sep 2017 06:02:25 GMT";
    Server = "Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/3.4.3";
} })
Response code: Optional(200)
Data: "{\"session_key\":\"somecodexyz1234\"}"
```

Comment: guard let dicResponse = responseJSON as? NSArray else{
                            return
                        } 

 add this in your response

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I tried changing the code to use `NSArray`, this still does not work as the else statement is executed.  The value of `responseJSON` before the guard is: `{"session_key":"somecodexyz1234"}`

Comment: Do no use Foundation class: Use Array instead of NSArray. "(the print(sk) is not executed as it is nil)" It shouldn't be executed because your code don't pass the if let... as Array test instead. Your JSON is a Dictionary, not an Array.

Comment: @Larme using `NSDictionary` does not work either `else` clause is still executed as the `code don't pass the if let as NSDictionary`

Comment: And what's the class of `json` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to get response from almofire in json. In Your code, your are directly checking response.data instead of first check response.result  as below.

```
Alamofire.request(requestURL, method:.post, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .success(let responseJSON):
                // If request success then you will get response in json here
                if responseJSON is String{
                    print("Reponse is string")
                }
                else if responseJSON is NSDictionary{
                    print("Reponse is Dictionary")
                }
                else if responseJSON is NSArray{
                    print("Reponse is Array")
                }
                else{
                    print("Any object")
                    return
                }
                print("Response : \((dicResponse)")

                break
            case .failure(let error):
                // If request is failure then got error here.
                break
            }
        })
```

Comment: Testing this code, the else statement is always executed, dicResponse is never printed

Comment: @hiren check his response get in NSarray not dictionary so put NSarray  instead of NSDictionary

Comment: @Anon957 Check the Type of response. Are you getting Array or Dictionary? As you mention in Question your response looks dictionary.

Comment: @Hiren I am getting a Dictionary. My server is very simple, running Python Flask. This is the code to return the response: `result = '{"session_key": "somecodexyz1234"}' return jsonify(result), 200`

Comment: @Anon Check the Type of Response object. I think you are getting string that way its return from guard keyboard.

Comment: @Hiren responseJSON has type `Any`

Comment: @Hiren My mistake, `Reponse is string`

Comment: @Anon957 yes Problem is on server side. Return dictionary or Array in response.

Comment: @Hiren Yes the problem was on the server side, updating the server to send json with appropriate mimetype set etc. has fixed the error. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using SwiftyJSON so why you again convert `let arr : NSArray = json as? NSArray` like this. You can simply do like this.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")

            print("Response code: \(String(describing: response.response?.statusCode))")

            if response.result.isSuccess, let result = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(result)

                // Here is your session key
                let sk = json["session_key"].stringValue

            } else {
                //Failure
            }
        })
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately . If i print `json` i get `{"session_key": "somecodexyz1234"}` but when I print `session_key` i get a blank line...

Comment: @Anon957 Yes because your json format is different. my answer is just one example. you can fetch as per your response format